# Why this behavior in the limit of sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The sequence $\{a_n\}$ that obeys the recurrence $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{\ 2\ +\ a_n}$ seems to converge to $2$ if $a_1 = \sqrt{2}$, but if $a_1$ were equal to $2$ instead, it would still converge to 2, isn't it right? Can it be deduced that for any $a_1$ lying in the interval from $\sqrt{2}$ to $2$, it would converge to 2?

Comment: Did you try to evaluate the limit when $\;a_1 =10\;$ , or when $\;a_1 = 556\;$ ...or $\;a_1=10^{10^6}\;$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(a) = \sqrt{2+a}$. Note that $f$ is only defined for $a \ge -2$. Note that $f([-2,2]) \subset [0,2]$ and $f([2,\infty)) \subset [2,\infty) $.
Also note that if $a \in [-2,2]$ then $f(a) \ge a$ and if $a \in [2,\infty)$ then $f(a) \le a$.

Look at the behaviour of $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$:
If $a_0 \in [-2,2]$ then $a_n$ is an increasing sequence bounded above and if $a_0 \in [2,\infty)$ then $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below.

Hence $a_n$ converges and hence $a= \sqrt{2+a}$, and since the only positive solution is $a=2$ we see that $a_n \to 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Let $a_n(x)$ be the value of $a_n$ for an initial value $a_1 = x$.  First show that $\sqrt{2} \le x < y \le 2$ implies $\sqrt{2} \le a_n(x) < a_n(y) \le 2$ for all $n$ using, say, induction.  Then show that this implies your result using a culinary-themed theorem about the convergence of sequences.

Comment: FYI, my answer is intended to show, specifically, that the fact that the sequence converges to $2$ for $a_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and for $a_1 = 2$ implies that it does so for all $\sqrt{2} < a_1 < 2$.  Of course, showing that sequence converges to $2$ for all $a_1 \ge -2$ is a stronger result.